# What to use instead of TaskException for ReviewManager Api?

Tags: android, kotlin

Trying to follow the google [tutorial for in-app reviews](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java#kotlin) and I'm currently stuck with the following piece of code:

```
val request = manager.requestReviewFlow()
request.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        // We got the ReviewInfo object
        val reviewInfo = task.result
    } else {
        // There was some problem, log or handle the error code.
        @ReviewErrorCode val reviewErrorCode = (task.getException() as TaskException).errorCode
    }
}
```

When I copy this into my IDE, it doesn't seem to pick up the `TaskException`. What could I rather use here as an alternative ?

I've added:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the documentation has a typo.

The correct exception cast should be this [RuntimeExecutionException](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/tasks/RuntimeExecutionException.html)

I've opened a [documentation issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195334544) about this

---

UPDATE: 11/01/2022 (dd/MM/yyyy)

Upgrading your `play:core` dependency to at least version [1.10.1](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/release-notes#1-10-1) will bring you a new custom `ReviewException` which should replace the `RuntimeExecutionException` (or at least this is what we think).

Without an official answer the current safest solution is probably the one below:

```
val errorCode = when (val exception = task.exception) {
    is ReviewException -> {
        exception.errorCode
    }
    is RuntimeExecutionException -> {
        exception.errorCode
    }
    else -> {
        9999
    }
}
```

You can use any value in place of 9999 but it is probably better if the integer is not already defined as error code in https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes just to avoid confusion

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade lib to v2.0.1

```
implementation 'com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1'
```

Replace TaskException with ReviewException in the code.

```
@ReviewErrorCode int reviewErrorCode = ((ReviewException) task.getException()).getErrorCode();
```