# Android Room either does not compile or throws error during runtime

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I wanted to use *Room* for storing data. For this I have my `AppDatabase.kt`:

```
@Database(entities = [SensorEntry::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun sensorDao(): SensorDao

    companion object {
        // For Singleton instantiation
        @Volatile private var instance: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
            }
        }

        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(
                context,
                AppDatabase::class.java, "SensorEntry.db"
            )
                .addTypeConverter(Converters::class)
                .addCallback(
                    object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                            super.onCreate(db)
                            ioThread { getInstance(context).sensorDao() }
                        }
                    }
                )
                .build()
        }
    }
}
```

using the following dependecies (from [developer.android.com])(https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room):

`build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    // optional - RxJava2 support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
    // optional - RxJava3 support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava3:$room_version"
    // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
    implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"
    // optional - Test helpers
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
    // optional - Paging 3 Integration
    implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:2.5.0-alpha01"
}
```

The database is instanciated in my `MainActivity`

```
val db = AppDatabase.getInstance(applicationContext)
```

I can compile the application but I get the error during runtime which is discussed here:
[Android room persistent: AppDatabase_Impl does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46665621/android-room-persistent-appdatabase-impl-does-not-exist)

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
```

---

No this thread suggest to replace the `annotationProcessor` in my `gradle.build` with `kapt`.
This seemed to do the trick, but then I get another error during comiling for which I've already openend a question [Using kotlin.UByte for Room Entity not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72434420/using-kotlin-ubyte-for-room-entity-not-working)

```
C:<...>\UInt8.java:15: error: Cannot find getter for field.
    private byte value;
Cannot find getter for field.
```

**Update**: I have purposely not included any code of object that should be stored. Please see my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72434420/using-kotlin-ubyte-for-room-entity-not-working) if you think, this might be the root of the problem.

Comment: i've removed a part of your question, we've [all been there before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68526347/what-to-use-instead-of-taskexception-for-reviewmanager-api), but let's not reduce the quality of your question for no good reason

Comment: is it possible that adding in `.db` to your database name is giving you issues ? looking through some of my previous work, i have never used that before, perhaps it makes no difference